# What is the use of uriAddress.GetLeftPart and how to use it in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the use of **uriAddress.GetLeftPart** and how do i use it in C#. Please provide one example. If i need to extract

```
http://localhost:2008/
```

part from

```
http://localhost:2008/ClientDashBoard/CreateDocument
```

Can i use **uriAddress.GetLeftPart** for doing that job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In general, if you have any question about a .NET class library method, I recommend having a look at the MSDN documentation as the first step. You can easily access it in Visual Studio by putting the cursor on the method in question and hitting F1. For example, the [MSDN page on Uri.GetLeftPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart(v=vs.110).aspx) has all the information you need:

> The GetLeftPart method returns a string containing the leftmost portion of the URI string, ending with the portion specified by *part*.
>
> [...]
>
> The following examples show a URI and the results of calling GetLeftPart with Scheme, Authority, Path, or Query.
>
> ```
> URI                                           Scheme   Authority               [...]
> http://www.contoso.com/index.htm?date=today   http://  http://www.contoso.com
> ```

So, apparently, `myUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` is (almost) exactly what you need.

Do note the following, though:

> GetLeftPart includes delimiters in the following cases:
>
> [...]
>
> Authority does not include the path delimiter.

So you will get `http://localhost:2008` instead of `http://localhost:2008/`. Fixing that is left as an exercise to the reader...